# Rails 3 authentication plugin suggestions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been using rails for a while and have used restful_authentication for user logins for the past few years. However this doesnt seem to be getting maintained any more, so was thiking it is time to move to another plugin.

Does anyone have any suggestiosn on what I should be using / is the most popular these days.

Only requirments I have are

- It needs to work with rails 3
- It needs to work with a model called Client instead of the standard User model.

Thanks,
Jon

Comment: Have a look at Devise: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 3 authentication solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236524/rails-3-authentication-solutions)

Answer (score 3):

Checkout [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), it's still maintained and there are a lot of support resources out there. It also has extendable plugins, so you can authenticate with Twitter, Facebook, or really any OAuth2 solution

Here are a few:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise
- http://www.kiwiluv.com/techblog/?p=397

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Devise:

http://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Answer (score 0):

Jon,

If you decide to go with Devise, note that you can manually override the default user class during installation. (The default is "User".) IMHO you're correct in that Devise seems to generally be maintained more, especially compared to restful_authentication. If you're torn between the two for your Rails 3 app, I'd recommend giving Devise a shot first.