# Zend_Authentication equivalent in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zend-framework

I am from Zend Framework background moving to Rails.

Are there any frameworks similar to Zend_Authentication in Rails?

It should handle

- various authentication adapters
- helper methods for logged_in? etc
- OAuth Support

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236524/rails-3-authentication-solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for Devise gem https://github.com/plataformatec/devise